# how to display data when user click on cell using javascript?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have grid that I built this way

```
Name Amt    Invoice
Tom  100    bla bla
Liz  200    bla bla
Sue  300    bla bla
Edd  400    bla bla
Mat  500    bla bla
```

I made the invoice colum invisible (Visible = False)

in my code When user select row 1 I need to read invoice details in the code behind.

I tried this

```
    protected void grd_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string Invoice = grd.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;
```

but Invoice is always empty

it works when I change the visibility to True and I can read it then

but I dont want the user to see this column

how can I do that?

Comment: Are you wanting javascript or are you using c#?

Also, you can hide a column in a gridview like this.dataGridView1.Columns["CustomerID"].Visible = false;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting column `Visible = True`, the data is emitted from the viewstate. Therefore the data does not appear on postback. To get around this, you can set `Visible = False` and hide the column using css. Alternativly use a hidden input.